# Unable to find element and input value using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My objective is to take a value (in my case a shipment tracking #) and input it into a tracking field on a website using selenium. I am unable to input the value and get the following error message:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chromedriver = "/Users/GUVA/Downloads/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("https://www.17track.net/en")

#data = df.values[1] # grabbing one tracking number from an excel file

# click "agree" to close window
python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="modal-gdpr"]/div/div/div[3]/button')[0]
python_button.click()

# enter tracking number into text box
que=driver.find_element_by_id('//input[@id="jsTrackBox"]')
que.send_keys("data")

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/GUVA/PycharmProjects/Shipment_Tracking/Track Shipment.py", line 26, in <module>
que=driver.find_element_by_id('//input[@id="jsTrackBox"]')
File "/Users/GUVA/PycharmProjects/Shipment_Tracking/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
File "/Users/GUVA/PycharmProjects/Shipment_Tracking/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
File "/Users/GUVA/PycharmProjects/Shipment_Tracking/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/Users/GUVA/PycharmProjects/Shipment_Tracking/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
(Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

`//input[@id="jsTrackBox"]` is an xpath. So you need to fetch the element by using `find_element_by_xpath` method(where you are currently using `find_element_by_id` method).

Your code should be like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chromedriver = "/Users/GUVA/Downloads/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("https://www.17track.net/en")

#data = df.values[1] # grabbing one tracking number from an excel file

# click "agree" to close window
python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="modal-gdpr"]/div/div/div[3]/button')[0]
python_button.click()

# enter tracking number into text box
que=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='jsTrackBox']//div[@class='CodeMirror-scroll']")
que.click()
que.send_keys("data")
```

Comment: Thank You. I was able to fix the error but I am unable to input the string "data" into the box.

Comment: @Goutham i have put an extra line in the answer where i am first clicking on the field and then entering the value. Please pick that from the answer and let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes, I did include the additional line where we click the box but it still does not work. Maybe my id="jsTrackBox" is wrong?

Comment: @Goutham i have edited the xpath, please pick the updated answer.

Comment: How did you get the xpath? When I right click on the element, this is not the xpath that I get. Even the updated xpath does not seem to work. The "from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys" is for some reason grayed out and maybe send.keys command is therefore not functioning

Comment: give `time.sleep(3)` before `que=driver.find_element_by_x...` line .  The `import` grey is not the issue - it is grey because you have not used `Keys` . Example use of `Keys` class is  - `send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat I am still unable to input anything into the textbox. I have used time `time.sleep(3)` like you have mentioned but as soon as the program runs `que.click()` it ends.

Comment: after `que.click` also add `sleep(3)` n check

Comment: Tried that and still does not work. Would you be able to try it out yourself and see if there is something wrong with my packages that causing the issue?